# Is $\left\{ e^{ \frac{2\pi i }{n}}: n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ compact in complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $\{ e^{ \frac{2\pi i }{n}}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$  compact in complex plane?

My answer is yes. It is bounded as $$ \left|e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}\right|=1$$ and the set is closed because it contains its limit point, $1$.
Can  I argue that a closed and bounded set in the complex plane ( regarding $\Bbb C$ like $\Bbb R^2$) is compact?
Little confused!

Thanks

Comment: Yes that is correct. If closed and bounded is your definition of compact then you are done, but if not then you might want to namedrop the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: Yes, for topological considerations, you can identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$, so "closed and bounded = compact" in $\mathbb{C}$ too.

Comment: Since it contains its limit point , which is $1$ , it should be closed. How do I argue? Can I directly argue "bounded and closed set is compact in $\mathbb{C}"$

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can say directly bounded and closed set is compact in $\mathbb{C}$, for a proof, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)

Comment: It's a sequence converging to $1$.

Comment: @anon yes indeed, thanks

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for pointing it out. I was careless

Comment: The given set is closed